# Crystal Reports Runtime

Tags: crystal-reports, runtime

i have an application that is dependent to crystal reports. now i want to deploy my application but i can not find crystal reports runtime. i found runtime that loads version XI (3.5).

i need version 2.8 which normally visual studio 2008 loads. i need the exact version on visual studio. do you know how i can find it?

i checked the website and i could not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

download the Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio .NET 2008

http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp#09

Comment: i just found before your answer with this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb971179(v=VS.90).aspx

thanks :)